# DateTime.ParseExact returning FormatExpcetion

Tags: c#, .net, string, exception, datetime

I have a strange problem:

```
string format = @"ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss \G\M\Tzzz yyyy";
__timestamp = "Fri Apr 09 17:02:00 GMT-0500 2010";
DateTime.ParseExact(__timestamp, format, new CultureInfo("en"));
```

returning `FormatException` = **"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."**

but that code going without exceptions:

```
string format = @"ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss \G\M\Tzzz yyyy";
__timestamp = "Sat Apr 10 01:27:00 GMT-0500 2010";
DateTime.ParseExact(__timestamp, format, new CultureInfo("en"));
```

From 30k of date parsing of that format, around 50% of that failed with that exception...

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it should be `HH` not `hh`. You're in the 24-hr format.

```
ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \G\M\Tzzz yyyy
```

Valid: `Sat Apr 10 01:27:00 GMT-0500 2010`

Answer (score 2):

Seems that DateTime is expecting AM/PM info for that "en" format provider. Try it with any hours less than 12 (inclusive), or add some AM/PM information